# IEnumerable<T> and IEnumerator - some clarification please

Tags: ienumerable, ienumerator

Good afternoon,

I'm currently reading the Pro ASP.net MVC 4 book published by Apress, and Im on the section which talks about extension methods.

I'm struggling to understand a section of code as follows:

```
 public class ShoppingCart : IEnumerable<Product>
{
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<Product> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Products.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I understand that the ShoppingCart class inherits a product IEnumerable.
I understand that we have created a method that returns an Enumerator of Product.
I do not understand the final method, IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator(). Can someone please enlighten me in 'newbie' terms?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last method you have to implement

```
  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
```

is a *heritage* of ancient .Net versions when .Net doesn't support *generics* (and `IEnumerator<T>`).
Since then, every `IEnumerable<T>` for compability reasons should not only implement

```
  IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
```

But old style non-generic

```
  IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
```

as well. You can see it just from the declaration

```
 public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable {...}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx